# How to access Orchestra Xml Parser through Laravel IoC Container

Tags: php, xml, laravel, parsing, ioc-container

I am using laravel 5.1. I want to use XML parser and I have searched and found [Orchestra](http://packalyst.com/packages/package/orchestra/parser) as mostly being used. So I have gone thorough all the steps given at [documentation](http://packalyst.com/packages/package/orchestra/parser) to install and configure. I have added `Orchestra\Parser\XmlServiceProvider::class` in `providers` section of `config/app.php` and `'XmlParser' => Orchestra\Parser\Xml\Facade::class` in `aliases` section.

Now in my controller, I have added its name space like `use Orchestra\Parser\Xml\Facade;` at the top of my controller. But when i try to use its function in my action, like

```
$xml = XmlParser::load($xml_document);
```

It generates error stating,

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\XmlParser' not found
```

So I want to know is there any other way in `Laravel 5.1` to use the packages and I am doing some thing wrong with `Orchestra` if some one has used it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since the documentation already describe registration of the facade alias:

```
'XmlParser' => Orchestra\Parser\Xml\Facade::class,
```

You can either use `\XmlParser::load()`, or import the alias.

```
use XmlParser;
```

or import the full namespace.

```
use Orchestra\Parser\Xml\Facade as XmlParser;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though it's searching inside the controllers for it..

Class 'App\Http\Controllers\XmlParser' not found

Therefore:

`$xml = XmlParser::load($xml_document);`

Needs to be:

`$xml = \XmlParser::load($xml_document);`

Should resolve this problem

Answer (score -1):

In Laravel 5.1 the controller is in a namespace. The XmlParser is in an other namespace. You need to include that namespace in your controller.

```php
<?php

namespace Orchestra\Parser\Xml; // Maybe this one is different

class Controller...
```

You can also add a \ to make it work.

```php
$xml = XmlParser::load($xml_document);
```

Comment: `namespace Orchestra\Parser\Xml;` isn't solving. It is generating Class 'Orchestra\Parser\Xml\Controller' not found